# How to build and link for specific GLIBC version

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, g++

My ubuntu build environment by default uses g++ 9.4.0 with this ldd version:

```
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.7) 2.31
```

My run environment is a hadoop environment that must be using a much older GLIBC because it gives me errors like this when I try to run myApp there:

```
./myApp: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by ./myApp)
./myApp: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by ./myApp)
./myApp: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by ./myApp)
./myApp: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./myApp)
```

I'm looking to resolve these errors in whichever way is easiest, but since I'm unsure of how to upgrade the hadoop environment, I'm starting with seeing if I can instead build using a lower GLIBC that will be available on the run environment. I'm struggling to understand how to accomplish this. To start, I've tried to install g++4.8 on the build environment as follows:

```
        sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8 g++-4.8  build-essential
        sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 10
        sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8 10
        sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cc cc /usr/bin/gcc 30
        sudo update-alternatives --list cc
        sudo update-alternatives --set cc /usr/bin/gcc
        sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/c++ c++ /usr/bin/g++ 30
        sudo update-alternatives --list c++
        sudo update-alternatives --set c++ /usr/bin/g++
        g++ --version
        gcc --version
        ldd --version
```

I was able to get this to install using bionic repos, but the ldd output is still GLIBC 2.31:

```
Setting up gcc-4.8-base:amd64 (4.8.5-4ubuntu8) ...
Setting up cpp-4.8 (4.8.5-4ubuntu8) ...
Setting up libasan0:amd64 (4.8.5-4ubuntu8) ...
Setting up gcc (4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up g++ (4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/g++ to provide /usr/bin/c++ (c++) in auto mode
Setting up build-essential (12.8ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libgcc-4.8-dev:amd64 (4.8.5-4ubuntu8) ...
Setting up gcc-4.8 (4.8.5-4ubuntu8) ...
Setting up libstdc++-4.8-dev:amd64 (4.8.5-4ubuntu8) ...
Setting up g++-4.8 (4.8.5-4ubuntu8) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.7) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 to provide /usr/bin/gcc (gcc) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/g++-4.8 to provide /usr/bin/g++ (g++) in auto mode
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/bin/gcc because link group cc is broken
/usr/bin/gcc
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/bin/g++ because link group c++ is broken
/usr/bin/g++
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.5-4ubuntu8) 4.8.5
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.5-4ubuntu8) 4.8.5
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.7) 2.31
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

When I run the resulting myApp on the run environment again, I get the same errors I noted above.

Is there a step that I'm missing to either force a specific GLIBC version or to update my build environment to use a g++ that defaults to a lower GLIBC version? I haven't found a way to use g++ 9.4.0 with say GLIBC_2.15 but can someone share with me tips on how that could be done?

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense to have a build container with exactly the OS that your hadoop system runs on? This just looks like you're looking down a loooong line of incompatibilities to arise, since you don't seem to have a toolchain specifically targetting your target system.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for the suggestion. I'm not sure of the best way of doing that from Github Enterprise. Seems like I would need to set up an EMR cluster in AWS just for running builds, add a local runner within that cluster, then run my build job there. I'm not sure if that'll be possible but I can give it a shot. I would need to find a way to spin the cluster up and down via the Github action too in that case.

Comment: @MarcusMüller your approach worked well. Thanks!